# Another Variable '__' used before being initialized question

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have searched here. I have seen and assume this is affecting it

> Class initialisation in Swift is a two-phase process. In the first
> phase, each stored property is assigned an initial value by the class
> that introduced it. Once the initial state for every stored property
> has been determined, the second phase begins, and each class is given
> the opportunity to customize its stored properties further before the
> new instance is considered ready for use.

When I run the below code I get the error `Variable 'self.string' used before being initialized`.

But it applies to every variable I don't change to a var and initialize. What is going on here?

Here is the error:

[image]

The below doesn't work.

```
struct IntTextField<T: Numeric & LosslessStringConvertible>: View {
    @Binding var number: T?
    @State private var string: String
    private let isDecimalAllowed: Bool

    private let title: LocalizedStringKey
    private let onEditingChanged: (Bool) -> Void
    private let onCommit: () -> Void

    public init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, number: Binding<T?>, isDecimalAllowed: Bool, onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }, onCommit: @escaping () -> Void = {}) {
        self._number = number
        self.string = "Why doesn't this work????"

        self.isDecimalAllowed = isDecimalAllowed

        self.title = titleKey
        self.onEditingChanged = onEditingChanged
        self.onCommit = onCommit
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField(title, text: $string, onEditingChanged: onEditingChanged, onCommit: onCommit)
            .numericText(text: $string, number: $number, isDecimalAllowed: isDecimalAllowed)
            .modifier(KeyboardModifier(isDecimalAllowed: isDecimalAllowed))
    }
}
```

The below works (I have to change them all to `var` and initialize them to something), why do I have to do this?

```
struct IntTextField<T: Numeric & LosslessStringConvertible>: View {
    @Binding var number: T?
    // Everything below is changed to var and initialized
    @State private var string: String = ""
    private var isDecimalAllowed: Bool = false

    private var title: LocalizedStringKey = ""
    private var onEditingChanged: (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }
    private var onCommit: () -> Void = {}
    // To here

    init(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, number: Binding<T?>, isDecimalAllowed: Bool, onEditingChanged: @escaping (Bool) -> Void = { _ in }, onCommit: @escaping () -> Void = {}) {
        self._number = number
        self.string = "Why does this work????"

        self.isDecimalAllowed = isDecimalAllowed

        self.title = titleKey
        self.onEditingChanged = onEditingChanged
        self.onCommit = onCommit
    }

    var body: some View {
        TextField(title, text: $string, onEditingChanged: onEditingChanged, onCommit: onCommit)
            .numericText(text: $string, number: $number, isDecimalAllowed: isDecimalAllowed)
            .modifier(KeyboardModifier(isDecimalAllowed: isDecimalAllowed))
    }
}
```

Comment: nice screenshot but the font is hard to read ;)

Comment: @AnderCover haha, I purchased Dank Mono which I loved in VSCode. I'm debating on my Xcode life.

Comment: Xcode and emacs are the two IDE I have really used, so if you don't like Xcode I can only tell you to try emacs ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That variable is a little different than normal because of its `@State` property wrapper. To initialize it here without that error, you need to do this:

```
self._string = State(initialValue: "Why doesn't this work????")
```

The `_` lets you access `string` without the property wrapper. In fact, you're already doing this on the line above with your `Binding` with a similar strategy.

On your second example, `string` already has a default value of `""`, so the compiler isn't worried about it not being set yet.

Comment: Of note, what makes this super confusing is if I change the declaration to: `@State private var string: String = ""` and keep the initializer as `self.string = "Why Doesn't this Work??"` the error then turns to `Variable 'self.isDecimalAllowed' used before being initialized` which lead the "Why does this work???" fix. I don't know why.